# Python regular expressions with more than 100 groups?

Tags: python, regex

Is there any way to beat the 100-group limit for regular expressions in Python? Also, could someone explain why there is a limit.

Comment: wow!, 100 is a big number for a regex :O

Comment: Can you explain why you need more than 100 groups? Perhaps we can help you find an alternate solution.

Comment: Yet again, I wish I'd dare to tag this you-dont-want-this.

Comment: I have the same problem. I'm trying to make a regex that matches subsequences for a set of strings `(a?b?)|(b?a?b?)|(a?a?a?c?)|...` and I need the groups to retrieve which original string the subsequence was a part of.

Comment: I ran into this problem when searching a large document for a large (externally provided) list of words in an efficient way by building a single RE from the list. To find out which word was found, I wrapped each word in a named group.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're doing exactly, but try using a single group, with a lot of OR clauses inside... so (this)|(that) becomes (this|that).  You can do clever things with the results by passing a function that does something with the particular word that is matched:

```
 newContents, num = cregex.subn(lambda m: replacements[m.string[m.start():m.end()]], contents)
```

If you really need so many groups, you'll probably have to do it in stages... one pass for a dozen big groups, then another pass inside each of those groups for all the details you want.

Comment: I used the or method you mentioned and a few tricks of my own. Thanks Jim.

Answer (score 10):

There is a limit because it would take too much memory to store the complete state machine efficiently.  I'd say that if you have more than 100 groups in your re, something is wrong either in the re itself or in the way you are using them.  Maybe you need to split the input and work on smaller chunks or something.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment. If you're hitting the 100 group regex limit, I think there's something wrong with the design.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree - what is "too much memory" and why should the module hard code this threshold? There are (rare) cases when this usage is justified. I have (sadly) come across such a case myself. I'm parsing a complex grammar with pyparsing and (alas) found out that pyparsing is too slow. I'm now auto-generating a regular expression to match my grammar (and I've hit the hard coded `100` brick wall).

Comment: I'm also using autogenerated RegExps, but to check for file inclusion of certain files. Each file is separated with an or (`|`) operator, and then the file is searched for by using `((caalog1/)?catalog2/)?file.hh`, if the relative path of the file is `catalog1/catalog2/file.hh`. This is because I want to match both `file.hh`, `catalog2/file.hh` and `catalog1/catalog2/file.hh`. Since I have quite a lot of files to check for, this becomes quite many groups...

Answer (score 9):

I found the easiest way was to

```
import regex as re
```

instead of

```
import re
```

The default _MAXCACHE for regex is 500 instead of 100 I believe. This is one of the many reasons I find regex to be a better module than re.

Comment: I don't have this module

Comment: A previous answer already proposes this solution, even if it does not put it as well as you did.

Comment: on debian-based unices, you can use `apt install python-regex` instead of pip

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, the "new" [regex](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) module (currently third-party, but intended to eventually replace the re module in the stdlib) does not have this limit, so you might give that a try.

Comment: You might want to improve your answer with the data form zambri’s and the comment in his.

Answer (score 5):

I doubt you really need to process 100 named groups by next commands or use it in `regexp` replacement command. It would be quite impractical. If you just need groups to express the rich conditions in `regexp` you can use non-grouping group.

```
(?:word1|word2)(?:word3|word4)
```

etc. Complex scenarios including nesting groups are possible.
There is no limit for non-grouping groups.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question.

Comment: True. I faced similar situation when I needed multiple groups. Non-grouping group was the solution. I struggle to believe more than 100 multiple named groups are really needed in good application design. I think it the correct solution is to avoid using so many named groups in the first place. Non-grouping group is a solution. There is no limit for those.

Answer (score 3):

First, as others have said, there are probably good alternatives to using 100 groups.  The `re.findall` method might be a useful place to start. If you really need more than 100 groups, the only workaround I see is to modify the core Python code.

In `[python-install-dir]/lib/sre_compile.py` simply modify the `compile()` function by removing the following lines:

```
# in lib/sre_compile.py
if pattern.groups > 100:
    raise AssertionError(
        "sorry, but this version only supports 100 named groups"
        )
```

For a slightly more flexible version, just define a constant at the top of the `sre_compile` module, and have the above line compare to that constant instead of 100.

Funnily enough, in the (Python 2.5) source there is a comment indicating that the 100 group limit is scheduled to be removed in future versions.

Comment: I would discourage anyone from modifying the standard library as this causes the application to work only on the local install. This leads to a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Python 3 doesn't have this limitation, whereas the same code ran in latest 2.7 displays this error.

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this I had a really complex pattern that was actually composed of a bunch of high-level patterns joined by ORs, like this:

```
pattern_string = u"pattern1|" \
    u"pattern2|" \
    u"patternN"
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string, re.UNICODE)

for match in pattern.finditer(string_to_search):
    pass # Extract data from the groups in the match.
```

As a workaround, I turned the pattern into a list and I used that list as follows:

```
pattern_strings = [
    u"pattern1",
    u"pattern2",
    u"patternN",
]
patterns = [re.compile(pattern_string, re.UNICODE) for pattern_string in pattern_strings]

for pattern in patterns:
    for match in pattern.finditer(string_to_search):
        pass # Extract data from the groups in the match.
    string_to_search = pattern.sub(u"", string_to_search)
```

Answer (score -1):

I would say you could reduce the number of groups by using non-grouping parentheses, but whatever it is that you're doing seems like you want all these groupings.

Answer (score -1):

in my case, i have a dictionary of n words and want to create a single regex that matches all of them.. ie: if my dictionary is

```
hello
goodbye
```

my regex would be: `(^|\s)hello($|\s)|(^|\s)goodbye($|\s)` ... it's the only way to do it, and works fine on small dictionaries, but when you have more tan 50 words, well...

Comment: Sounds like the same problem to me, with the same solution: `\b(hello|goodbye|whatever)\b`  If that doesn't work, ask a new question so we can help you properly.

Comment: Yours is an example of how not to write a regular expression.

Answer (score -2):

It's very ease to resolve this error:
Open the `re` class and you'll see this constant `_MAXCACHE = 100`.
Change the value to `1000`, for example, and do a test.

Comment: You generally don't want to change built-in classes, as this causes an application to work only on your own install. This leads to a maintenance nightmare.

Comment: Writing `re._MAXCACHE=1000` doesn't seem to do the trick. The error still happens

Comment: The OP did not complain about the cache - He complained about the limit of the number of groups. Sadly that number is hard coded in the module. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/478849/78234

Comment: See @Triptych's answer. `_MAXCACHE` is not used to create the 100-group limit. Did you try this out yourself, or did you just see that constant in the code and guessed?